# Prevent parent's sibling's event from triggering in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<input id="test" type="text" list="list">
<datalist id="list">
    <option value="A">First option</option>
    <option value="B">Second option</option>
</datalist>
```

```
$("input").keyup(function(event) {
    //any event like this for example...
    console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

I don't want this event to trigger after the user clicked on an option. Already tried the followings even though it was unlikely to work (javascript) :

```
$("option").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also why does the event trigger since I used a `keyup` event and not an `input` ? ...

Comment: You can [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the `$("input")` keyup event instead of trying e.prevenDefault which is preventing the default action of option's click event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do with [`Keypress`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keypress.asp).

**UPDATED**

you need to call the value from the event inside not a onload

```js
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
  //any event like this for example...
  console.log("Hello from the other side");
});

$('#test').change(function(){ // you need to call the value from the event inside not a onload
console.log(document.getElementById("test").value) //no need
console.log($(this).val()) // jquery alredy present so simple use that
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text" list="list">
<datalist id="list">
    <option value="A">First option</option>
    <option value="B">Second option</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks. Still there's a fishy issue : if my code would be :
`console.log(document.getElementById("test").value);` I wouldn't be able to see the current input, because the event triggers before the input's value is changed... which is not fine to me !
I need it to trigger after the input value has changed. Any idea ?

Comment: I am having further problems. I want to prevent the event, no way around. Have you got any solution please?

Comment: Which event ..? Can you explain bit more